# Getting around the 8192 byte var limit in NSIS?

Tags: c++, json, dll, nsis

I'm supplying a c++ .dll to a user who is writing an installer via an NSIS script. Using System.dll, the user can call my .dll as such:

```
System::Call 'my.dll::GetJson(v) t .r0'
DetailPrint $0
```

The return value of GetJson() gets stored in $0. This is all working correctly, though GetJson() may return a json blob whose length is > 8192, in which case the value stored in $0 gets truncated.

I looked at trying to increase NSIS_MAX_STRLEN by building NSIS myself using scons, as mentioned here: https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Special_Builds

```
 scons NSIS_MAX_STRLEN=16384 PREFIX=C:\somewhere install-compiler install-stubs
```

However, after doing this, the NSIS-compiled .exes crashed upon running. It seems like 8192 may be some kind of memory limitation.

Is there any way around this for me? For example, would it be possible to call

```
System::Call 'mydll::GetJson(v) t .r0'
```

But instead of the return value being stored in $0, have it be split into chunks? Perhaps it's possible to write the contents of GetJson() to a file first, and then NSIS can read that and split it?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If splitting the string is acceptable, does that mean you don't need to parse/modify the string in NSIS?

Comment: @Anders Oof great point. The user will need to parse that JSON, so splitting probably won't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user needs to edit a very long string you basically have two options:

Use the system plug-in to fill a text field on a nsDialogs custom page. You can't use the registers to store the string, you need to use `...func()p.r0` to get the raw address of the string from your plug-in and use Sendmesage to fill the text field. To save you need to allocate memory, get the text with SendMessage and write it to a file and finally free the memory.

The other option is to create the custom page with your custom plug-in.

Comment: Ah, that is an interesting technique. Thank you for the help.